# Slick generic query with distinctOn

Tags: scala, slick

I would want to make a generic slick query using distinctOn on table to count distinct elements in the column.

```
def countDistinct(table: TableQuery[_], column: Rep[_]): DBIO[Int] =
  table.distinctOn(_ => column).length.result
```

This code above doesn't compile because:

```
No matching Shape found.
[error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.
[error] Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection,
[error]  you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List),
[error]  or you forgot to import a driver api into scope.
[error]   Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
[error]      Source type: slick.lifted.Rep[_]
[error]    Unpacked type: T
[error]      Packed type: Any
[error]     table.distinctOn(_ => column).length.result
```

`FlatShapeLevel` instead of `Rep[_]` also doesn't work. I'm using slick 3.

Answer (score 1):

`distinctOn` doesn't work properly in Slick due to incorrect projection to a particular field/column. The [bug](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1340) was raised 5 years ago, surprisingly still hasn't been resolved.